# windows 10 install python PIP does not work

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to get PIP working on my computer, but it keeps telling me the module isn't found.

```
C:\CODE\SCRIPTS\python>where python
C:\TOOLS\PYTHON\python.exe
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
    
C:\CODE\SCRIPTS\python>where py
C:\Windows\py.exe

C:\CODE\SCRIPTS\python>python --version
Python 3.10.11

C:\CODE\SCRIPTS\python>python -m pip --version
C:\TOOLS\PYTHON\python.exe: No module named pip

C:\CODE\SCRIPTS\python>python -m ensurepip --default-pip
C:\TOOLS\PYTHON\python.exe: No module named ensurepip

C:\CODE\SCRIPTS\python>python get-pip.py
Collecting pip
  Using cached pip-23.1.2-py3-none-any.whl (2.1 MB)
Collecting setuptools
  Using cached setuptools-67.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting wheel
  Using cached wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
Installing collected packages: wheel, setuptools, pip
Successfully installed pip-23.1.2 setuptools-67.7.2 wheel-0.40.0

C:\CODE\SCRIPTS\python>py -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
C:\TOOLS\PYTHON\python.exe: No module named pip

C:\CODE\SCRIPTS\python>python -m ensurepip --default-pip
C:\TOOLS\PYTHON\python.exe: No module named ensurepip

C:\CODE\SCRIPTS\python>py -m pip --version
C:\TOOLS\PYTHON\python.exe: No module named pip

C:\CODE\SCRIPTS\python>py -m ensurepip --default-pip
C:\TOOLS\PYTHON\python.exe: No module named ensurepip
```

Comment: What is the contents of your `PYTHONPATH` environment variable?

Comment: @mark-ransom `pythonpath` and `pythonhome` were not set.  I have set them both to my python folder, `C:\tools\python` which is where python was installed to and where `python.exe` is located.  I can run `get-pip.py` and it says successful, but module `pip` and module `ensurepip` error with `No module named pip or ensurepip`

Comment: The only reason it would say "no module" is because it can't find the module.  The place it looks for the module is determined by `PYTHONPATH`, notice that it's all upper case.  You can include more than one path in the variable.